# How does spring come to know about the new request or session?

Tags: java, spring, requestscope

I know in a web application, for every request it gets, spring creates a new instance of the bean in ints container. 
I want to know how does spring differentiate between the requests and create new instances of bean accordingly?

Comment: "for every request it gets, spring creates a new instance of the bean" - who told you that?

Comment: 11th min [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnNvDknQJt0&index=11&list=PLzQekfF9y7ZcXPmw1s4bVaZaPPQWOHb3-)

Comment: http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-bean-scope-example-using-scope-annotation-and-xml-for-singleton-prototype-request-session-global-session-and-application-scope-with-scoped-proxy#request

Comment: only as long as the beans are request scoped

Answer (score 1):

This work is done by [Request context listener](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/RequestContextFilter.html) where it takes  the decision of instantiating beans based on incoming http request and discarding them once their life cycle is over. Session , Request scope beans are only relevant if the application context web aware, if otherwise IllegalStateException  will be thrown.

And also refer -
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other